# In angular2 I'm having trouble getting CanDeactivate working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In angular2 I'm trying to get CanDeactivate working.
I'm currently using my homepage route to test this functionality.

Outcome I'd like is: Redirect a user to another page if they are not authenticated.

I'm using typescript with angular2 and I have the latest libraries and stable angular2 app.

I've had an attempt below to try get it working.

**my attempt at the home route file:**

```
     import { Route, CanDeactivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HomeComponent } from './index';

export const HomeRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [CanDeactivateTeam]
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [CanDeactivateTeam]
  },
  {
    path: 'homepage',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [CanDeactivateTeam]
  }
];

class UserToken {}

@Injectable()
class Permissions {
  canDeactivate(user: UserToken, id: string): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}

@Injectable()

class CanDeactivateTeam implements CanDeactivate<HomeComponent> {
  constructor(private permissions: Permissions, private currentUser: UserToken) {}
  canDeactivate(
    component: HomeComponent,
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
    return this.permissions.canDeactivate(this.currentUser, route.params.id);
  }
}
```

**This is my new error:**

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Token must be defined!

Answer (score 1):

- Add `pathMatch: 'full'` to the empty path route. Are there more details to the error message?
- Add `@Injectable()` to `Permissions`

```
@Injectable()
class Permissions {
  canDeactivate(user: UserToken, id: string): boolean {
```

- Ensure you provide `CanDeactivateTeam`, `Permission`, and `UserToken`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  providers: [CanDeactivateTeam, Permission, UserToken],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I've updated my code above. Can you spot any errors?

Comment: The error message indicates that you added `HomeModule` to `providers: [...]` instead of `imports: [HomeModule]`.

Comment: The code above is for the homeModule and the homeRoutes so I dont need to import homeModule?

Comment: Seems like it doesnt like this: import { CanDeactivateTeam, UserToken, Permission } from '@angular/router';

Comment: Of course not. `CanDeactivateTeam, UserToken, Permission` are not exported by `@angular/router`.

Comment: where do I import them from?

Comment: From the files where you defined them in.

Comment: you mean this: import { CanDeactivateTeam, UserToken, Permission } from './home.routes';

Comment: if `./home.routes.ts` is the file where you put the classes, then yes.

Comment: im confused because im doing everything in home routes, so why I need to import it to home module? these are the same route but 2 separete files. I've updated my code. Seems like its complaining now about route.params.id

Comment: Hard for me to tell because I can't see the full picture because I only have limited information about what you're doing. You don't need to import into the current file what is defined in that file. You only need to import if you want to use something from other files.

Comment: I want to check if the user is logged in before showing them this component, if they are not logged in then redirect them else where. I'm using home page just to play with it and get it working

Comment: What is the current status?

Comment: I get this error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Token must be defined!"

In my code it doesnt seem to like this line:     return this.permissions.canDeactivate(this.currentUser, route.params.id);

Comment: I don't think the error message is related to this code line. `Token must be defined!` looks more like a DI configuration problem. Can you try to reproduce in Plunker? There is just not enough information to debug your problem from here.

Comment: That's the latest code I have, not sure what else to try?

Comment: As mentioned, try to reproduce in a Plunker. I'm pretty sure the error message is not caused by above code.

Comment: I dont know how to use plunker

Comment: It's not complicated. The `[New | V]` button provides a ready-to-use Angular2 template.

Comment: As soon as I add canActivate: [CanDeactivateTeam] to the route it gives me that token error

Comment: Ive read all those docs. I've followed it in my example. What am I missing in the above code?

Comment: I don't know because your above code is not complete. If you can reproduce in a Plunker I know that all code is there that is necessary to reproduce the problem. Currently I can only ask my crystal ball but it's all foggy. Perhaps I should buy a more expensive one.

Comment: What code do you need me to add above? I've noticed that my route doesnt have an id and its asking for one e.g. "route.params.id"